# Angular momentum in baryon multiplets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, angular-momentum, group-representations, baryons

In the Murray Gell-Mann model, particles are brought together as a function of their angular momentum. 
The classification diagrams can be seen as irreducible representations of $SU(3)$, following multiplication rules $3\otimes 3\otimes 3$=$10\oplus 8\oplus 8\oplus 1$.

My question is: must $J^p$ be equal between each of these decuplet, octets, and singlet? (Is there a $J^p=1/2^+$ baryon decuplet?)

I know it is the case for the mesons, but I am not sure if this is by chance or it is demanded.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your questions is ***no*** , and for your parenthetical specific question, *yes*--but it may be a weirdo one.

First, review your generic, flavor-blind quark [assignments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon#Spin.2C_orbital_angular_momentum.2C_and_total_angular_momentum). The total *J* comes as a combination of the three *s*=1/2 quarks and the orbital *L*, which enforces its even or odd parity *P* to the baryon. The total w.f. must be fermion interchange antisymmetric, is color antisymmetric, so the combination of flavor SU(3) and spin/angular momentum part must be over-all symmetric. Since the **10** is flavor-symmetric, its combination *J* w.f. must be symmetric.

The decuplet that contains the *Ω*-,  which is just 3 *s*trange quarks, must be spin symmetric for *L*=0, so then *S*=*J*=3/2+ . This is a fact of nature, the confirmation linchpin of SU(3), historically, which provides a counterexample to your first question/mis-conjecture.

The trailing parenthetical question of (*is there...*) is answerable in the affirmative, in principle, for *S*=3/2, *L*=2, resulting in a 1/2+, but it would take enormous and improbable baryon-spectroscopic gumption to isolate and confirm a state like that...

As for your oddly flawed rule for the mesons... you have a pseudoscalar meson octet and a vector meson octet, [see the two figures here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson#Isospin_and_charge). How would your rule work? In this article, you see the analogous spin/angular momentum composition rules for the mesons.